# Get swf file functions names using ExternalInterface?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, externalinterface

I found many examples on internet how to call swf file function via ExternalInterface.
What i want to know is, is it possible to enumerate somehow swf file functions so i can choice which to call ?

Comment: Why would you want to enumerate functions in swf file? You can call it by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what the asker is wondering, is if there's a way to retrieve all public functions from an SWF (iterate instead of enumerate).
In that case, the only way I know of would be to create a function like getFuncList() which returns a list of all functions. This does require you to have access to the SWF source however.

Comment: Can't i just partially decompile the format, so i get the names ?

Comment: If you've got a decompiler and the SWF isn't obfuscated, sure. But why exactly are you trying to access functions you're not meant to know of? What I mean is, if you were meant to know the functions, you would have them by now.